# where is Doctrine_Pager?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

i want to use this:

```
$pager = new Doctrine_Pager(
                $query,
                $page,
                $results_per_page
);
$results = $pager->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$num_results = $results->getNumResults();
```

but i cant seem to find the doctrine pager file or class...
`$pager = new \Doctrine\Pager;   not there...

i usuall use the doctrine entity manager by:

```
 $this->_doctrine = Zend_Registry::get('doctrineEm');
```

do i have to download this, if so, where from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Doctrine 2.0 they eliminated Doctrine_Pager.
Doctrine_Pager exist only in Doctrine 1.2.
I found on github doctrine of extensions for 2.0 that might be useful:

https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions

https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta

Comment: @timdev, could u give a sample code, how we use Zend_Paginator and DoctrineExtensions\Paginate\PaginationAdapter or DoctrineExtensions\Paginate\Paginate ???